# Proper expression for when you want to say "reduce the workload of someone"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I was wondering whether you could help me in choosing the most suitable word/expression.

Can I say that "I want to reduce the workload person X faces" or is there a better expression? What I am trying to say is that the I want to help person X by doing some of the work he is supposed to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Colloquially you can say, “Let me *lighten your load*”  or “What can I do to lighten your load?”

Comment: Thank you for asking. The bad news is that this is the wrong place for your question. This site is about the English language itself: word meanings, pronunciation, spelling, grammar, history. For advice on writing, writing styles, or academic standards, one of these other sites might be helpful: [academia.se], [writers.se], [literature.se], [workplace.se], [interpersonal.se]. If you are learning English, take a look at [ell.se]. If you want to try another site, please ask for migration, or else delete here before re-asking the question on the other site. See: [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"He needs help and I've decided **to absorb part of his workload**."
"He's gone on leave and had **to absorb his workload**."

This means I'm doing part of his work myself.

> - [**absorb**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/absorb) -  to take in or assimilate, incorporate.

e.g.

- "..., so colleagues don't feel frustrated if they have to help absorb someone's workload due to a mental health-related sick leave."[**¹**](https://issuu.com/keymedia/docs/hrdca2.3_emag)
- "Perhaps his colleagues are still willing to absorb his workload, but more probably they are getting a little weary and impatient with the additional workload."[**²**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=y7a5R5IjMGIC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=willing+to+absorb+his+workload&source=bl&ots=lwb5DSsOoW&sig=zBmP-ER9jYTSf0E9Imcb3iRXRME&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix0o2g7LPeAhWII5AKHbXeBWUQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ)
- "Do you have suggestions to help us absorb his workload and maintain our stamina?"[**³**](https://fraze.it/sentences_using_stamina)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than saying "I want to reduce the workload person X faces," you could say:

> I want to **alleviate** his workload.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*alleviate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alleviate):

> : RELIEVE, LESSEN: such as
>
> **a** : to make (something, such as suffering) more bearable
> // Her sympathy *alleviated* his distress.
> **b** : to partially remove or correct (something undesirable)
> // measures taken to *alleviate* a labor shortage